# CSV Download - Chrome issue

Tags: flask

On one of my routes, a CSV file is downloaded to the user with an incremental filename each time it is executed.

I've hit some kind of caching issue in Chrome - subsequent executions download the original file - but Safari on a mac works fine every time.

I've googled it, and added cache_timeout=0 - but that didn't resolve my issue. I don't want to generate a file in an IOstream as some others have suggested elsewhere. Any easy fixes, or shall I redirect to a URL with part of the filename embedded in the URL?

```
return send_file(path, as_attachment=True, cache_timeout=0)
```

Comment: can you check if the `app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0` setting works?

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of solutions to this (that should work)

1. Set the `Cache-Control` header to `no-cache`
   This just tells Chrome not to cache it, but it can be overridden by the user.
2. Add `?{query param}={random value}` to trick chrome so it will send the request out and ignore the cache.
   Since the URL is different, Chrome will not get it from cache since it will think the file is different.